# Change Custom dialog of ANR(Application not responding) dialog (Android)

Tags: android

I am writting an applications launcher (like home screen application). And I am wondering whether we can intercept the default dialog occurs when some application doesn’t respond in 5 seconds. What I want is: instead show the default alert dialog the launcher will show another dialog. I was googling for a while but haven’t found anything. Could anyone please tell me whether it is possible ?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This dialog is a system dialog, warning the user Android can't let this app do its job because it seems to have crashed. So I don't think this dialog would be allowed to be changed. Why would you want to change it anyway ?

Comment: I want to translate it to my language (Vietnamese) and change some content so the users from my country know what to do.