# What is ANR Dialog in android?

Tags: android

I want to know about ANR dialog in android applications and when it will happen and how to remove that. 
Please help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handle ANR(Application not responding) dialog (Android)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385323/handle-anrapplication-not-responding-dialog-android)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ANR - application not responding.

This dialog appears when the main thread of the application is blocked for too long, for example, when you sleep on this thread, or performing a long connection.

Avoiding it is done by moving the heavy operations to other threads. There's a great article regarding the ways to implement that - [Painless Threading](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2009/05/painless-threading.html).

Comment: The article seems to have been moved to: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html

Answer (score 2):

It will happen when you spend too much time on the main application thread. To avoid ANR errors, ensure any long-running work occurs on a background thread.