# How ANR dialogs shows while MainThread is in Blocked state

Tags: android

I am reading `ANR`. Most of things make sense to me but i can not understand that if Main thread is blocked then How OS create a `Dialog` in same process and show it on screen . From the Documentation:

> An ANR will be triggered for your app when one of the following conditions occur:
>   1. While your activity is in the foreground, your app has not responded to an input event or `BroadcastReceiver` (such as key press or screen touch events) within 5 seconds.
>   2. While you do not have an activity in the foreground, your `BroadcastReceiver` hasn't finished executing within a considerable amount of time.

i.e The main thread is in a deadlock with another thread So how the OS manage to show a dialog . Cause i think we can only show dialog from a main thread.  Please correct me if i am wrong and let me know the process of `ANR` dialog.
 Any explanation will be really appreciated. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because it's not your app that is responsible for showing the dialog. The system handles it. From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/anr.html)

> If the app is in the foreground, the **system** displays a dialog to the user

So when you app is ANR, an external "app" (or intent if you will), will handles the popping of the dialog that allows you to terminate the ANR app...

Also, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20213482/what-is-the-difference-between-anr-and-crash-in-android) to understand the difference between ANR and crash

Comment: So you mean the `Dialog` open from a `Context` of another app(System App) ?

Comment: Yes. It's a `system dialog`... It's raised by the OS itself. Read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385323/change-custom-dialog-of-anrapplication-not-responding-dialog-android)

Comment: There is a special Intent to be listening (i.e. broadcast listener) if you want to manually handle (mostly close) a system dialog. It's called [ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS)